# To get EditText value of another layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Inside a Fragment class I tried to get EditText value of another layout xml file in Fragmen.class.

I tried like shown below but I am getting empty value.

```
     public class Fragmen extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_b, container, false);

             View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_a,null);
             EditText ed = (EditText)view1.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
             String mm = ed.getText().toString();
             //here I am getting mm as null
             return view;


            }

                  }
```

Comment: You can only get references to widgets from layouts that have been inflated in a current view. If you have more than one `Fragment` in your `Activity` then they should pass data to the `Activity` and the `Activity` should pass that dat to the different `Fragments` when needed.

Comment: @dmsherazi : Your comment makes no sense. A `Fragment` should never know of the existence of any other `Fragment` - there's no guarantee that any other `Fragment` has been created, attached to an `Activity` or that its view has been inflated.

Comment: @Lazy Ninja How it will be duplicate